# I need to clean a SQL table and erase all entries older than now, *and* move upcoming entries "up one".. best way?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an SQL table where users have listed their next three upcoming art shows.

I'm putting together a cron job maintenance script and I would like it to erase shows that have already happened.  But then I would also like to "move the others up one".. so that show1 is erased, but show2 becomes show1, show3 becomes show2, and show3 is now empty.

Is this the best way to approach this? (Using Codeigniter BTW) Note that for each show there is actually other info (show1title, show1desc, etc) that I would have to move .. but I have reduced it here for clarity.

```
$_sql = "SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.show1date < CURDATE() AND users.show1date != 0000-00-00";
$_query = $this->db->query( $_sql );
if ($_query->numRows() > 0){
    foreach ($_query as $_row) {
        $_id = $row->id;
        $_show2date = $_row->show2date;
        $_show3date = $_row->show3date;
        $_sql = "UPDATE users SET users.show1date = ?, users.show2date = ?, users.show3date ='' WHERE users.id = ?";
        $_query = $this->db->query( $_sql, array($show2date, $show3date, $_id) );
    }
}
```

This would "move all the shows up" and leave show3 now empty.  Is this a good way to go about this?  It seems like there might be a better way?

Now that I'm thinking .. maybe a separate table for shows with the user.id as a foreign key?

Comment: The *best* way would definitely be having a separate table for shows, as you say. That way, you'd just have to drop outdated records without having to change anything else

Comment: Seperate table is better. But i don't see why the records needs to be move up? Let's say, 3 person a, b, c are in a line in the order. If i kick a out, then b and c will move up even if they don't move. So what is the logic you are trying to apply here?

Comment: I've decided to go with a separate table.. it seems it's going to be a lot easier that way. I had originally stored only one show with a user, so it was not a big deal.  Now that I store three, I wanted to erase ones that have passed, but try to keep a consistent system of "show3 is always the one that gets filled by a new entry".  It seems it just makes much more sense to put it in a different table, although I will have to change some logic downstream.  If you write an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Just for the record if you're going to redo your structure anyway add an active field to the shows table, then set that to 0 or whatever for inactive and 1 or again whatever for active. Deleting things from a database messes with the indexes created and will generally slow performance more than having more records. It also means you never actually lose data and could reuse or reference it should the need ever arise.

Comment: @RickCalder  Thanks.  I already have that on my users table so I was going to continue that.  It's good to know it is best practice.  And so I guess its safe to say that if you are somehow often "shuffling around" values of fields in a table, it's probably a clear indicator that a separate table would be beneficial too.